# How to tell rustc (through cargo) where to find my dll import library

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo

I'm producing a dll with mingw to be used by rust. I know I can place my `libxxx.a` file in the `"Rust\bin\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib"` directory, and that's what I'm doing now. But I'd rather keep it in my project's directory. How do I get Cargo to tell rustc where to find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you can use `cargo rustc` to pass the `-L dir` parameters to rustc directly:

```
cargo rustc -- -L lib
```

if your library is located in `lib` subdirectory.

Another, probably more convenient, way is to use a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) to pass library directory to rustc automatically. It then will be used with other cargo commands as well, like `run`, `test`, etc. If you store the following code to `build.rs`:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=native=foo");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=lib");
}
```

(assuming your library is called `libfoo.a`)

and then add `build` key to `[package]` section in Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
...
build = "build.rs"
```

then it should find your library automatically upon every build command.

Note that the build script is also a nice place to actually *build* your library. Cargo documentation contains examples and links on that.

Comment: The first works. But the build script gives an error, saying *"unknown library kind `native`, expected one of dylib, framework, or static"*.  I got it to work by removing `=native` from both lines.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, it looks like it is some kind of version mismatch for cargo. I took these examples from the official cargo documentation.

Comment: Playing around with it some more, it's strange. I tried putting "dylib" and "static", and nothing at all in that part of the string (where you put "native"), and they all work fine. Though using "framework" it complains about not being on OSX, as expected.